# _this8.setState is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, asp.net-core

I seem to be having an issue setting state in my React app.  I'm still learning React so it could very well be an easy fix.

Currently I have the following set up for a component that exists to grab data from a page I'm serving from .NET Core.  I know that it's serving the data correctly because I can debug the page and see the data within the response variable I'm getting.  However when trying to set state, I get an error that states "_this8.setState is not a function".  I've searched StackOverflow and I keep seeing posts about "_this2.setState is not a function", and they recommend bindings.  I've tried a variety of binds, on the different methods within my React app, but so far no dice.  I'll share my React code below:

```
// GET Request to data
class TableBodyData extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    updateTable() {
        $(function () {
            $.getJSON("/table", (res) => {
                const MAP_DATA = res.data;
                this.setState({ MAP_DATA });
            });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateTable();
    }

    render() {
        return (
             <TableBody data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

// Renders body of Table where data is input
class TableBody extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.data.refDataType}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
         );
     }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: All the problem come because you are using $(function() and this is not an arrow function, hence, this  is not preserved and will not be the react class. If using componentDidMount you shouldn't need to wait for the dom to be ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i was having the same problem in my react application.
first and for most you need to understand the 'this' keyword.
when 'this' keyword is called inside a method inside a object, it means the object itself without passing any parameter or arguments in that method. however this can be tricky if you call 'this' inside a method belonging to object which has a argument.
look at this code:

```
updateTable(){
     (()=> {('table', (res)=>{
       const Map_data = res.data;
this.setState({Map_data});})})()}
```

in above example this.setstate will not work properly. becuase this refers to the argument passed in as 'res'. instead use the bind method on updateTable method when calling the function. inside the component Like so:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.updateTable.bind(this)
}
```

this will ensure when component are rendered they will bind this keyword with that function.

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside callback method represent the callback instead of the React class instance.

change :

```
 updateTable() {
            $(function () {
                $.getJSON("/table", (res) => {
                    const MAP_DATA = res.data;
                    this.setState({ MAP_DATA });
                });
            });
        }
```

To:

```
updateTable() {
        $(()=> {
            $.getJSON("/table", (res) => {
                const MAP_DATA = res.data;
                this.setState({ MAP_DATA });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: or better yet, get rid of that unnecessary wrapper completely

Comment: Ved Thank you very much!  I don't generally use non-specific indicators much, and so I thought this was referencing the entire class generated by React instead.  I'm all solved now, thank you very much!

Comment: azium I ended up doing that.  The reason I wrote that up in the first place was it was the same style a fellow coworker wrote his React code, and I was trying to not change much so I can debug easier.  Thank you as well though!